# The code injects a third-party Qt application and performs some methods to get Qt application information

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Code injection can get the Qt application I developed correctly, but third-party applications can't. What should I do?

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DoSomeThing();
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        DoSomeThing();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}


void DoSomeThing() {
LPCTSTR step = L"GetQCoreApplication";
LPCSTR CustomApplications = "CustomApp";
LPCSTR ThirdPartyApplications = "ThirdPartyApp";
//CustomApplications = ThirdPartyApplications;
HWND hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, CustomApplications);
DWORD procId;
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procId);
HANDLE handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, procId);

/*Custom programs are available. But third-party applications are not available.*/
QCoreApplication* qCoreApplication = QCoreApplication::instance();
if (qCoreApplication != NULL) {
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Get QCoreApplication", TEXT("Inject Code"), MB_OK);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Not Acquired QCoreApplication", TEXT("Inject Code"), MB_OK);
}

ofstream mcfile;  
mcfile.open("D://Inject.txt");  
mcfile << "This is my message.";  
mcfile.close(); 

/*Custom programs are available. But third-party applications are not available.*/
HWND hwnd11 = FindWindowA(NULL, CustomApplications);
QWidget* q = QWidget::find((WId)hwnd);

if (q != NULL) {
     //
}
else {
    // 
}

}
```

Custom programs are available. Third-party applications are not available.

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at the qt dynamic library, I found Qtxxxd.dll and Qtxxx.dll. Check out the qt documentation and find that the qt application uses Qtxxxd.dll in debug mode and Qtxxx.dll in release mode.
Make sure your injection program is consistent with the injected program using the same pattern.